# How to publish ASP.NET Web Application with Angular 4 from MS Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio, angular-cli

I have a web application that uses ASP.NET (server-side) with Angular 4 (client-side). The project was created in MS Visual Studio as a ASP.NET Web Application. When I want to publish my web application, I do it by these steps.

1. I publish my ASP.NET Web Application from MS Visual Studio.
2. I run the Angular-CLI build command in PowerShell `ng b --prod`.
3. I copy the Angular build result into the folder that I published my ASP.NET Web Application to.

The problem is that I need to run the Angular-CLI build command and copy the build result to the web folder every time I want to publish my web application.

Is it possible to set the publish tool in MS Visual Studio to run Angular-CLI build command before, then publish with the build result? So, I can just use the publish tool in MS Visual Studio to publish my web app.

Comment: Just an idea which I did not try. Could you try to use Pre- or Post- Build events and run the PowerShell commands from the event?

Comment: I used to use post-build event in another project long time ago. I understand that both pre- and -post build event are not working in case of publishing. But I will try it. Thank you.